# Why are all my edges being assigned the same value in a networkx DiGraph?

Tags: python, graph, nodes, networkx, edges

I have been stuck on this simple problem for awhile and cant quite figure out the solution. I have a dictionary that is structured like {(node1, node2): weight} called EdgeDictFull. I wanted to create a DiGraph that has the weight stored as an attribute in the graph. I have tried a whole bunch of different ideas but no seem to work.  When I run this code....

(weights is just a list of all the weights I want to add to the edges as attributes)

```
TG = nx.DiGraph()
for x in weights:
    TG.add_edges_from(EdgeDictFull.keys(), weight = x)

TG.edges(data = True)
```

What this does is it will create all the correct edges, but all edges will have the attribute value of the last integer in my weights list. I think I understand why it does that, however, I cant seem to figure out how to fix it. I know it's something really simple. Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 0):

```
# the problem with your code is that in every iteration of your loop you add
# *all* edges, and all of them get the same weight.

# you can do either of  the following:

# zip:
TG = nx.DiGraph()
for edge, weight in zip(EdgeDictFull.keys(), weights):
    TG.add_edge(*edge, weight=weight)
    
# or directly work with the dictionary:    
## dummy dictionary:
EdgeDictFull = {(np.random.randint(5),np.random.randint(5)):np.random.rand() for i in range(3)}

TG = nx.DiGraph()
TG.add_weighted_edges_from((a,b,c) for (a,b), c in EdgeDictFull.items())
    
    
TG.edges(data = True)
```